# Remove rows from dataframe with matches from another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes such as:

**gene_bacteriadf**

```
 seqnames    ranges strand
  [1] scaffold_1      1-50      -
  [2] scaffold_1    60-100      -
  [3] scaffold_1   200-350      -
  [4] scaffold_2 1550-1650      +
  [5] scaffold_2 1900-2300      -
  [6] scaffold_5   250-255      +`
```

and **overlapdf**

```
seqnames    ranges strand hit with_busco with_bacteria Overlap_with 
scaffold_2 1550-1650      + |      TRUE       101        201        101 0.502487562189055
```

and the idea is simply to remove the matching in columns seqnames, ranges and strand.
I tried;

```
genes_bacteriadf[!(alist(genes_bacteriadf$seqnames, genes_bacteriadf$start, genes_bacteriaf$end, genes_bacteriadf$width) %in% (alistoverlapsdf$seqnames,overlapsdf$start,overlapsdf$end,overlapsdf$width), ]
```

But id does not work.

Here in the exemple scaffold2 1550 165à does match so I should get a new df such as:

```
seqnames    ranges strand

  [1] scaffold_1      1-50      -
  [2] scaffold_1    60-100      -
  [3] scaffold_1   200-350      -
  [5] scaffold_2 1900-2300      -
  [6] scaffold_5   250-255      +
```

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for dplyr's `anti_join`, especially with the same column names.

```
library(dplyr)

gene_bacteriadf %>% 
  anti_join(overlapdf)

Joining, by = c("seqnames", "ranges", "strand")
    seqnames    ranges strand
1 scaffold_1      1-50      -
2 scaffold_1    60-100      -
3 scaffold_1   200-350      -
4 scaffold_2 1900-2300      -
5 scaffold_5   250-255      +
```